# How many (separate) Keycloak clients for different platform versions of app?

Tags: flutter, keycloak

I have an application which is built using Flutter and hence has 4 versions for each major platform/OS (Android, iOS, macOS and Windows) which are distributed via the respective app stores. The functionality of all these app versions is (almost) the same - i.e. only some minor differences in how certain features are implemented, but their overall functionality is the same.

When adding Keycloak as an IDP, I was asking myself the following question. The answer might be obvious, but I couldn't really find an explicit one yet so far:

Do I need to (or is it advisable) to create a separate client in Keycloak (more precisely the respective realm) for each of the app's platform versions (i.e. 4 different clients - one for the Android, iOS, macOS and Windows version) or can/should I use the same Keycloak client for all of them? Are there any advantages or disadvantages to one or the other approach?

Besides these 4 versions of the app, I have a REST API which handles access to the users' resources in the database. I assume that at least this API should have its own (confidential) client?

Given that all the app's platform versions have the same functionality, I do not really need to distinguish between certain access permissions etc. Even further, one major feature of the app is that it provides the same functionality on all different platforms.

One aspect I was thinking about is that if I had separate clients, then also the user's sessions for each app version/operating system would be managed via separate clients in Keycloak. But if I had just one client, then one user could have multiple sessions for different versions of the app within the same client. Would this cause any issues? (However, even if I had separate clients for each operating system, I could potentially still face this issue if a user is for instance using the iOS app on their iPhone and iPad - both of which would then be using my "iOS client" in Keycloak).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The question essentially comes down to: Do I need to create a separate client in Keycloak for each app (iOS, Android etc.) or can all of them use the same client?